# Div background image not filling the div

Tags: html, css

I have a div and span element inside a parent div one div has the background image of  a picture on my system, but the background image isn't occupying the whole image, please why is it like that, I just want to put images side by side with texts under them

The css

```
.img-w {
   position: relative;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 150px;
   width: 200px;
              }
```

The html

```
<div style="width: auto;height: auto"><div class="img-w col-md-3 col " id="    {{$image->id}}" style="background-image: url('{{$image->filename}}')" data-src="    {{$image->filename}}">
 </div><span style="    color: #333333;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
text-align: justify;
display: inline;">{{$image->description}} <i class="fa fa-upload" style="margin-left: 10px; color:#333333;"></i><br/> <br/></span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try putting the width and height on your parent div? Then make .img-w width and height 100%

—

So Make the parent div height 150px and the width 200px then .img-w width and height 100%

Answer (score 0):

Here is a better way to create an element with an image background. You can make a background image dynamic easily if required

```css
              
.container {
    position: relative; 
    max-width: 100%; /* Maximum width */
    margin: 0 auto; /* Center it */
}

.container .content {
    position: absolute; /* Position the background text */
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black background with 0.5 opacity */
    bottom:0;
    color: #f1f1f1; /* Grey text */
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    padding: 20px; /* Some padding */
}
```

```html
<div class="container col-md-3 col">
<img src="https://www.gettyimages.ie/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/UK/CMS_Creative_164657191_Kingfisher.jpg" />

  <div class="content">
    <span>What is Lorem Ipsum?
      <i class="fa fa-upload" style="margin-left: 10px; color:#333333;"></i><br/> <br/>
      </span>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50770855/div-background-image-not-filling-the-div#
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this will lead you to end your question.

Greetings!

Comment: Which span do you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

try this

https://jsfiddle.net/7h16z3yx/

```css
.img-w {
   background-image: url(https://www.fg-a.com/wallpapers/white-background-geo-shapes.jpg);
  position: relative;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 150px;
  width: 200px;
}

.img-text{
   color: #333333;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    justify-content: center;
}

/* demo theme */
.img-w {
  border : 2px solid #929292;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div style="width: auto;height: auto">
  <div class="img-w col-md-3 col ">
  <span class="img-text">text
    <i class="fa fa-upload" style="margin-left: 10px; color:#333333;"></i>
 </span>
  </div>
  
</div>
```